# All reference values in Excel sheet becomes '!#REF! when refering values from another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

One of our excel program stops working and I am trying to figure out why.

In the program, there are multiple sheets. The one cannot calculate value is called "Piston", and the reason is that all reference values from another sheet called "General Input" fail to refer.

The following are some failed cells in "Piston" sheets:

```
='General Input'!#REF!*(0.0063/0.0111)*EXP(-1*0.0214*$C$9)
='General Input'!#REF!*EXP(-1*0.0214*$C$9)
=AB5*(AD5+AC5*DG5)/(AD5+AB5*DG5)/'General Input'!#REF!
=$C$8*0.0000032/('General Input'!#REF!*Piston!$C$4*Piston!N10*(2*$C$6/1000)^2*('General Input'!$C$16/1000)^2)
=((BV9^3)*(BQ9^2)/DJ9/8+(BW9^3)*(BR9^2)/DK9/4+(BX9^3)*(BS9^2)/AE9/4+(BY9^3)*(BT9^2)/DL9/4+(BZ9^3)*(BU9^2)/DM9/8)/12/'General Input'!#REF!*$G$26/(1000000)^3
```

Apparantly all different values in "General Input" fail suddenly at the same time. I am not the one who wrote the code, and I don't use it as well. I am just asked to fix the bug.

But I just want to ask, is there any reason that suddenly make all referred value fail from a sheet?

Sorry if the information I provided is too vague.

Comment: are you deleting a range on the General Input sheet?  That will cause ref errors...

Comment: At some point, those REF! items pointed to particularly places which no longer exist. Either the cells themselves were deleted, or a link to another workbook was cut, or they referred to a legitimate location once but were copied elsewhere and the relative reference ran it off the page. There is no way to get it back without accessing a version of the file without these errors, or manually recreating the references yourself.

Comment: If there are macros within the file, it's quit possible that something in the code execution does something to wipe out the reference as @Grade'Eh'Bacon points out.

Comment: A good rule of thumb is to *always* check for instances of #REF! as you change a workbook. Allowing invalid references to creep in "when they dont matter" makes it harder to see them when they really do matter.

Answer (score 0):

!#REF! used to be a cell reference - e.g. $G$9

```
 ='General Input'!#REF!*(0.0063/0.0111)*EXP(-1*0.0214*$C$9)
```

However, such link/reference to G9 doesn't exist anymore - e.g. G9 was deleted.

The best hope is that you saved different version of such Excel. If yes, go back to an older version and copy those formula.

Good luck.

Comment: Thank all of you for the help. Unfortunately I don't have the original file without these errors, so I will have to give up.